# Does PPAD really capture the notion of finding another unbalanced vertex?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reductions, search-problem, ppad

Complexity class **PPAD** was invented by Christos Papadimitriou in his seminal 1994 [paper](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/papers/On%20the%20Complexity.pdf). The class is designed to capture the complexity of search problems where the existence of a solution is guaranteed by "Parity argument in directed graphs": if there is an unbalanced vertex in a directed graph then there must exist another one. But usually the class is formally defined in terms of the $\mathsf{ANOTHER\ END\ OF\ THE\ LINE}$ ($\mathsf{AEOL}$) problem, where the argument is applied only to graphs with both in- and outdegrees $\le 1$. My question is: why are these notions equivalent?

Up to this point it is a duplicate of [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/why-are-these-two-definitions-of-ppad-equivalent). Now I want to state the problem formally and to clarify why I am not satisfied with the answer there.

Search problem $\mathsf{ANOTHER\ UNBALANCED\ VERTEX}$ ($\mathsf{AUV}$): we are given two polynomial-sized circuits $S$ and $P$ that get $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ and return a polynomial list of other elements in $\{0,1\}^n$. These circuits define a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{0,1\}^n$ and $(x,y)\in E\Leftrightarrow (y\in S(x)\land x\in P(y))$. The search problem is the following: given $S$, $P$ and $z\in V$ such that $indegree(z)\ne outdegree(z)$, find another vertex with the same property.

Search problem $\mathsf{AEOL}$: the same, but both $S$ and $P$ return either an empty list or one element.

The notion of reducibility (corrected according to Ricky's suggestion): total search problem $A$ is reducible to total search problem $B$ via polynomial functions $f$ and $g$ if $y$ is a solution to $f(x)$ in problem $B$ implies $g(x,y)$ is a solution to $x$ in problem $A$.

**Formal question**: why is $\mathsf{AUV}$ reducible to $\mathsf{AEOL}$? Or should we use another notion of reducibility?

Christos Papadimitriou proves analogous theorem about **PPA** (Theorem 1, page 505) but the argument seems not to work for **PPAD**. The reason is that a vertex with degree balance $\pm k$ will be transformed into $k$ vertices with degree balance $\pm1$. Then the algorithm for $\mathsf{AEOL}$ may get one of these vertices and return another one. This would not yield a new vertex for $\mathsf{AUV}$.

Things are getting worse because in $\mathsf{AEOL}$ there is always an even number of unbalanced vertices but in $\mathsf{AUV}$ there might be an odd number of them. This is why one cannot build a bijection between these two sets and $g$ could not be always equal to $f^{-1}$. If $g(x,f(x))\ne x$ then we obtain a method for solving $\mathsf{AUV}$ in polynomial time at least for some instances. If $g$ does not depend on $x$ and $g(y_1)=g(y_2)$ for $y_1\ne y_2$ then $y_2$ may be returned as an answer for $y_1$. That would not give a solution for $\mathsf{AUV}$.

**Final question**: can the obstacles listed above be somehow overcome? Can one employ possible dependence of $g$ on $x$?

Comment: "why are these notions equivalent?" ​ For the reasons given in the proof of Theorem 1 on page 505 by Christos Papadimitriou. ​ (Otherwise, what do you think is a _parity_ argument for the totality of AUV?) ​ Your definition of reducibility seems too strong - For example, under your definition, expanding the set of solutions can make a total search problem strictly harder. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I think that undirected parity means that every edge contributes 1 to two vertices' degree, and directed parity means that every edge contributes +1 to one vertex balance and -1 to another vertex balance. The construction for PPA works for my definition, and what is the right one? Your last point is indeed very interesting!

Comment: +1 and -1 have the same parity. ​ (That parity is "odd".) $\hspace{3.09 in}$ The right one has "implies $g(x,\hspace{-0.03 in}y)$" instead of "iff $g(\hspace{.04 in}y)$". ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky I have changed the definition of reduction but I think that my obstacles persist.

Comment: Now, what we _do_ have is that, I'll call it UnbalancedInOtherDirectionVertex, _that_ problem reduces to [PPADS](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppads), since one can flip the edges if necessary to make the given vertex have greater out-degree than in-degree, and then the $k$ total-degree-1 vertices the given vertex gets transformed into will all be sources rather than sinks. ​ I don't see any similar way of going from your problem to AEOL. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: At least the reduction shows that AUV is equivalent to its case where all vertices have indegree and outdegree at most 1 except possibly for the given vertex z, which has indegree 0, but may have large outdegree.

Comment: Wow, what an observation! It is surprising how errors are discovered after more than 20 years in that paper (see also https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2015/163). Let me contribute with a Sperner-lemma type complete problem for AUV: Given a triangulated $3k$-gon whose vertices are colored with 3 colors such that the boundary vertices are colored cyclically, find a rainbow triangle. (Here $k$ is part of the input.)

Comment: To be fair, Papadimitriou’s paper does *not* actually claim that AUV is in PPAD (though the vague wording somewhat suggests it). It is, however, claimed (without proof) in the Beame–Cook–Edmonds–Impagliazzo–Pitassi paper.

Comment: Yes, it is also claimed in several surveys and lecture notes.

Comment: I've just heard from Frederic Meunier that he has also observed this problem five years ago and Papadimitriou agreed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems have been proved to be equivalent (and thus PPAD-complete), see Section 8 in [The Hairy Ball Problem is PPAD-Complete by Paul W. Goldberg and Alexandros Hollender](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07657).

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that the proof appeared in an earlier technical report by the same authors: [The Complexity of Multi-source Variants of the End-of-Line Problem, and the Concise Mutilated Chessboard](http://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2018/120/)

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting question, and I can only give a partial answer.

It is easy to see that the construction on p. 505 of Papadimitriou’s paper shows the equivalence of **AUV** with its special case

> **MANY ENDS OF THE LINE (MEOL):** Given a directed graph $G$ with in-degree and out-degree at most $1$ (represented by circuits as above), and a nonempty set $X$ of sources of $G$, find a sink or a source $v\notin X$.

On the one hand, I find it hard to imagine a transformation of such graphs that could reduce a larger number of sources to one.

However, on the other hand, **MEOL** belongs to all commonly studied classes containing **PPAD** except possibly **PPAD** itself:

First, obviously,

> **MEOL** is in **PPADS**.

I will sketch below an argument that

> **MEOL** is in **PPA**

by reduction to the standard **PPA**-complete problem (the undirected version of **AEOL**). Assume we are given $G=(V,E)$ and $X$ as in the definition of MEOL.

If $|X|$ is odd, we can just make the graph undirected, include a matching on all but one vertex from $X$ (as in the argument on p. 505), and pass the result along with the remaining source from $X$ to the **PPA** oracle.

In general, let $s=|X|$, and $2^k$ be the largest power of $2$ that divides $s$. We define a new graph $G'=(V',E')$ whose vertices are $2^k$-element subsets of $V$. If $A,B\in V'$ are such sets, we put the edge $(A,B)$ in $E'$ if we can enumerate the sets as $A=\{a_0,\dots,a_{2^k-1}\}$, $B=\{b_0,\dots,b_{2^k-1}\}$ in such a way that $(a_i,b_i)\in E$ for each $i<2^k$.

Clearly, $G'$ is a directed graph with in-degree and out-degree at most $1$. An $A\in V'$ is a source (sink) iff it contains a source (sink, resp.) of $G$. (That is, if it contains both, it is an isolated vertex.) So, any such vertex would lead to a solution of the **MEOL** instance, unless $A$ is a “known source”: that is, $A\cap X\ne\varnothing$. We intend to make the graph undirected, and manipulate it so that the number of known sources is reduced to $1$ by including a matching on the remaining ones.

So, if $A$ is a known source, let $t=|A\cap X|$, which satisfies $0<t\le2^k$. If $t=2^k=|A|$, then simply $A\subseteq X$. The number of such sets is $\binom{s}{2^k}$. Recall that the multiplicity of a prime $p$ in $\binom ab$ equals the number of carries in the addition $b+(a-b)=a$ performed in base $p$. By the choice of $k$, it follows that $\binom{s}{2^k}$ is odd. Moreover, there are polynomial-time bijections between $[0,\binom ab)$, and $b$-element subsets of $[0,a)$. Using this, we can define a polynomial-time matching on all but one of $2^k$-element subsets of $X$. We include it in the graph, which reduces the number of known sources with $t=2^k$ to $1$.

For $0<t<2^k$, the carry-counting formula shows that $\binom st$ is even. Again, we can find an explicit matching on $t$-element subsets of $X$. We extend it to known sources $A$ with $|A\cap X|=t$ by applying the matching to $A\cap X$, and leaving $A\smallsetminus X$ fixed.

In this way, we produce an undirected graph with one known leaf vertex. We ask the **PPA** oracle for another leaf, and by construction, we can extract from it an answer for the **MEOL** instance.

---

As briefly mentioned by Papadimitriou, we can generalize **PPA** to classes **PPA**-$p$ for any prime $p$. An example of a **PPA**-$p$ complete problem is

> **AUV**-$p$: Given a directed graph $G$, and a vertex whose degree balance is ${}\not\equiv0\pmod p$, find another such vertex.

(See [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/37794) for the equivalence of **AUV**-$p$ with Papadimitriou’s definition of **PPA**-$p$.)

**PPA**-$2$ is just **PPA**. The classes **PPA**-$p$ are assumed to be pairwise incomparable, and incomparable with **PPADS**. They all include **PPAD**.

There was nothing particularly special about $p=2$ in the argument I outlined above, and it can be easily modified to yield

> **MEOL** is in **PPA**-$p$ for every prime $p$.

Comment: I like the answer very much and have decided accept it (of course, more complete answers are still welcomed). I only think that the class represented by **AUV**-$p$ should be called **PPAD**-$p$. Papadimitriou writes about undirected bipartite graphs and just degrees, not balances.

Comment: The classes are generalizations of PPA, not PPAD, for $p=2$. Papadimitriou gives a different complete problem than AUV-$p$ (note that his graphs are bipartite), but it is equivalent to my definition. The whole naming scheme is terribly confusing; the usage of directed vs. undirected graphs for a particular class is just an accident, many of the classes have complete problems concerning both directed and undirected graphs (as in the case of PPA-$p$).  Also, despite their names, most of the classes are *not* based on parity arguments, but other counting principles. Only PPA is about parity.

Comment: Thanks, got it. It is indeed the same class. I have heard a speculation that Papadimitriou has chosen the name PPAD because it resembles his own surname.

Comment: Do you have a reference for PPAD being in PPA-p?

Comment: Not an explicit one, but for instance, the defining PPAD-complete problem is literally a special case of AUV-$p$.